# How do i write/paste a captured image to a doc file?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a scenario where i need to capture image and write them to a word file one after the other. I have written the below code but doesn't seem to be working. Please help

```
          Robot robot;
          try {
          robot = new Robot();

          BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
          ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File("C:\\xxx\\Gaurav\\NEW1.JPG"));
          InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
          XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
          XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
          run.setText(resulttext);
          run.addPicture(is, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "new", 300, 300);
      } catch (AWTException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      //Blank Document

}
```

Comment: As far as I see there will nothing be written into your `ByteArrayOutputStream baos`. Maybe `ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", baos);`.

Comment: Didn't work....

Comment: `.flush()`ed the `ByteArrayOutputStream` before using its byte array to create a `ByteArrayInputStream`? Otherwise, what error occurs? Which wrong behavior occurs?

Answer (score 2):

Using `ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", baos);` the image is there but it is a little bit small because the measurement unit is not pixel but EMU (English Metric Unit). There is a `org.apache.poi.util.Units` which can convert pixels to EMUs.

The following does work for me:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class CreateWordPictureScreenshot {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

  String resulttext = "The Screenshot:";

  Robot robot = new Robot();

  BufferedImage screenShot = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  //ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", new File("NEW1.JPG"));
  ImageIO.write(screenShot, "JPG", baos);
  baos.flush();
  InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
  baos.close();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.setText(resulttext);
  run.addPicture(is, XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG, "new", Units.toEMU(72*6), Units.toEMU(72*6/16*9));
  is.close();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordPictureScreenshot.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: This does work.. One question, how can multiple screen shots be taken and placed one after another in the same doc file ?

Comment: Can you please help here ?

Comment: No, this is another question. So please ask another question. And please refine your requirement description. Is the requirement to start the program and then take multiple screen shots every n seconds and place them one after another in the same doc file and then end? Or is the requirement to start an application and this application handles an event (button click, key stroke, ...) which then takes a screen shot on every action and place them one after another in the same doc file and saves the doc file if the application ends? If the latter, what kind of application? Swing?, JavaFX?, ...?