# How can I add image in paragraph run using poi word?

Tags: apache-poi

everyone ! I am exporting word in poi word, I want to add a image in my header, but I am failure. There are many questions in stack overflow about this problem, but I could not find any answers. I using the poi-3.15.jar, below is my code. Can anybody give me some advice? Add text is successfully but image is failure.

```
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        paragraph.createRun().setText("hhhhh");
        InputStream a = new FileInputStream("2.png");
        paragraph.createRun().addPicture(a, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "2.png", 20, 20);
        saveDocument(document2, "D:\\4.docx");
```

Comment: Your code only seems to be adding text to the main document body? Where's the code for working with the header that isn't working?

Comment: because I want to create a paragraph in my header, and this paragraph add the image, I have tested when I add the run(this run add a image) in my header, it is does not work. Let us see the code above only, and the addPicture() method is also does not work.

Comment: "Let us see the code above only, and the addPicture() method is also does not work.". Inserting pictures in document body **is** working. But your inserted picture is a little bit small because the measurement unit is not pixel but EMU (English Metric Unit) and 20 EMU is 20/914400 inch. There is a `org.apache.poi.util.Units` which can convert pixels to EMUs. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065534/how-do-i-write-paste-a-captured-image-to-a-doc-file/42072473#42072473

Comment: `CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(document, sectPr);
  headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(STHdrFtr.FIRST, paragraphs);` Yeah, you are right, I can add image in run(paragraph) successfully, but when I add this paragraph (including run)into header, and it is also does not work, and I can not open my .docx file.  Above is my code, the image is added in the paragraph. what is wrong about my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with inputting pictures in `XWPF` header/footer until `apache poi` version 3.15. See [Add image into a word .docx document header using POI XWPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097640/add-image-into-a-word-docx-document-header-using-poi-xwpf)

But in `apache poi` version 3.16 Beta 2 it seems to be fixed since the following code works using `apache poi` version 3.16 Beta 2:

```java
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;

import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

public class CreateWordHeaderFooter {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  // create header-footer
  XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy headerFooterPolicy = doc.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
  if (headerFooterPolicy == null) headerFooterPolicy = doc.createHeaderFooterPolicy();

  // create header start
  XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Header:");

  InputStream a = new FileInputStream("file_icon.png");
  paragraph.createRun().addPicture(a, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "file_icon.png", Units.toEMU(20), Units.toEMU(20));
  a.close();

  // create footer start
  XWPFFooter footer = headerFooterPolicy.createFooter(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Footer: ");

  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHeaderFooter.docx"));
  doc.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested your code? When I using your code but there is a error: when I open the .docx file, there is a red wrong symbol and says: **The image cannot be displayed.Your computer may not be have enough memory to open the image, or the image may have been corrupted.Restart your computer, and then open the file again.If the red X still appears, you may have to delete the image and then insert in again.** I using the 3.16-beta2.jar, what's reason of this error?

Comment: The code is tested and works for me using apache poi version 3.16 Beta 2. Please check that you are not only using `poi-3.16-beta2.jar` but also **all** other jars from version 3.16 Beta 2. **Don't** mix up jars from different apache poi versions! Also are you sure, there is not really simply a problem with your `2.png` file?

Comment: According to the error message this seems to come from an `Word` for `Mac`. This is not tested since I am not using, have never used and will never using `Apple` products. But if so, this is then an `Word` for `Mac` problem only.

Comment: Thanks so much, It is can work now. I am fail before because I am not using all other jars from 3.16 Beta 2. Thanks!

Comment: `paragraph.createRun().addPicture(InputStream, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imagePath, width, height)` I used this code to add image in my word, but image is different under different conditions. So image's height and width cannot be fixed, so how can I set adaptive size for image, thanks! @Axel Richter

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "set adaptive size for image"? But also: This is a new question and cannot be answered in this old question. So ask a new question, provide **all** relevant informations about what you have and what you need and show code (a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)) to reproduce the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to add image using XWPF run method.

```java
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;                               
                                                                               
String imgFile = "C:\\poi-3.9\\pictures\\Picture1.jpeg";                       
XWPFParagraph p = document.createParagraph();                                  
XWPFRun r = p.createRun();                                                     
int format = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG;                                   
try {                                                                          
    r.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), format, imgFile, Units.toEMU(400),
            Units.toEMU(100)); // 200x200 pixels                               
} catch (Exception e){                                                         
    System.out.println (e.getMessage());                                       
}
```