# Word Doc is corrupted when i add the images using Apache POI

Tags: java, xml-parsing, apache-poi, docx

I am trying to save screenshots in the word document using Apache POI, But when i try to open that word document , I am getting XML Parsing error

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFParagraph par = docx.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run = par.createRun();
   run.setText("Hello, World. This is my first java generated docx-file. Have fun.");        run.setFontSize(13);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Jar files\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.get("http://www.google.com");
   driver.manage().window().maximize();

   TakesScreenshot scrShot =((TakesScreenshot)driver);

   //Call getScreenshotAs method to create image file

           File SrcFile=scrShot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

       //Move image file to new destination

           File DestFile=new File("F:\\Jar files\\Prin.png");

           //Copy file at destination

           FileUtils.copyFile(SrcFile, DestFile);
           Thread.sleep(2000);
           driver.close();
    InputStream pic = new FileInputStream("F:\\Jar files\\Prin.png");
    run.addPicture(pic, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "3", 0, 0);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("F:\\Jar files\\OG2.docx"); 
    System.out.println("Success");
    docx.write(out); 
    out.close(); 
    pic.close();
```

Word Document Screen Shot:
[XML Parsing Error Scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUkLc.png)

[XML Parsing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrPcy.png)

Comment: Show us the relevant part of the XML document.

Comment: 1: I would do `pic.close();` before `docx.write(out);` since the picture data will be needed completely while writing. 2: But I suspect the picture file had be simply not already written, even not after `Thread.sleep(2000);`. 3: After `run.addPicture(pic, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "3", 0, 0);` your picture will be 0 pixels width and 0 pixels height. This is al little bit small, is'nt it? 4: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065534/how-do-i-write-paste-a-captured-image-to-a-doc-file/42072473#42072473 I have provided a code to write screen shots into word using `Robot`. This works.

Comment: I am getting the same XML Parsing Error after adding Robot Class for ScreenShot   ,,I attached the XML for reference...Pkease help me to resolve this.

Comment: The XML lacks the whole content of the `<pic:pic>...</pic:pic>`. Please show the code which has produced this. What happens if you are using exactly the same code I have provided in my linked answer? If you are using this code already, then please tell us the environment and the `apache poi` version you are using. The code is tested and works using `apache poi` version 3.17, Java 8, OS Windows and Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Thanks Axel Richter , Its  working fine now, Before I was using apache poi version 3.9 , now i changed it to 3.17 as you suggest, Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: You are welcome. Always take a look at [Apache POI - Download Release Artifacts](https://poi.apache.org/download.html) and use the latest stable version since `apache poi` is highly in development. And of course their version numbering is weird. After 3.9 follows 3.10, then 3.11, ..., 3.17. Should better had been 3.09, 3.10, ..., 3.17 or 3.9, 4.0, 4.1, ...

Answer (score 0):

Updating poi-ooxml to latest (3.17) from 3.8 worked.